# Lost ability to move anchor points in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, anchor-point

I have been working on this project for almost a week, and have been moving single points just fine using the direct select tool. At first, I was struggling with how to select and move a single point. I found if I clicked it 3 times, moving on the third click, it would move just fine for me.

Now even that isn't working.

I assume I changed an option or something, but do not know what it was.

Final Answer:
Just using the 'A' allowed me to isolate the single anchor point to be moved.

Thank You Lucian

Comment: `A` merely activates the Direct Selection Tool. You shouldn't need "3 clicks" with it either. Just one. Sounds like maybe you were using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use A to Select direct selection tool or the white arrow in tools panel...and if you are not able to see the anchor points even after selecting the tool then Go to View - Show edges...That will make the anchor points visible again.

Comment: Thank you very much - This is also the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just clicking in the wrong place or have something (de)activated.

Check if any of the layers are locked, or any of the artwork is locked. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>F7</kbd> and look at the Layers panel.

Or, try a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and then hit <kbd>A</kbd> for the `Direct Selection Tool` and try to select anchor points this way.

Or, try a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, which is an on/off feature to hide/un-hide some of the stuff appearing as selected on the artwork.

Comment: Thanks Lucian - I don't think the layers are locked - it occurs when I create a brand new

Comment: Thanks Lucian - Nothing highlights when I hit CTRL+ALT+2.  I tried selecting all the objects and using Object (Uncock/Unlock All) , the options are greyed out.

Comment: Just added a few more things to my answer above. Hard to guess without looking at the actual file.

Comment: Is there a way to send you the actual file?

Comment: I guess, but really sounds like a misuse of AI, we don't actually provide 1:1 support here, just answering questions. I think you'll need to go through some of the basics of the selection tools available in AI.

Comment: CTRL+ Y then the A works.  Could it be I am using up too much memory?  CTRL-Y appears to display only the frame.  Which I assume is using up the memor.

Comment: I actually took a class 2 years ago, but a refresher wouldn't hurt me..  Thanks for the answer

Comment: CTRL+Y is a "wireframe only" view, useful for when you have alot of overlapping and/or grouped/masked shapes, among other things. Nothing to do with memory. Glad to help !

Comment: Correct Answer:  A for the Direct Selection Tool and try to select anchor points this way.